# Accessing previous versions of papers in EasyChair

Tags: peer-review, tools, workflow, automation

EasyChair allows authors and chairs to "replace" previous versions of a submission. Is it possible to access previous versions?

(Context: I'm interested in the extent to which EasyChair supports a review process where papers are revised in the light of reviewers' comments, and reviewers/editors need access to prior versions of papers to check that particular issues have been dealt with.)

Comment: Actually a  new version of a paper should stand on its own. "Did the author kowtow to the reviewers" should not be a concern. I find it objectionable if it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the list of submissions, click on the "information" icon (blue ball with a letter "i" in it) next to the paper title, then you will see a "previous versions" link.